# UIActivityIndicatorView for Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, uiactivityindicatorview

Is't there a "NSActivityIndicatorView" for Mac OS X like the UIActivityIndicatorView for iOS?

How can I show a spinning "gear" during long activities?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use NSProgressIndicator.

Here is an initialization of it.

```
NSProgressIndicator* indicator = [[[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20, 20, 30, 30)] autorelease];
[indicator setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
```